Why label cannot be declared before end
Below code works perfectly
DECLARE
 x NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
 LOOP
  IF x > 5 THEN
   GOTO my_label;
  END IF;
  dbms_output.put_line(x);
  x := 1 + x;
 END LOOP;

 << my_label >> 
 x := 100;
END;

but if i remove x := 100 then its showing below error.
ORA-06550: line 13, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
 ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null raise
   return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge standard pipe
   purge json_object

I know labels should appear directly in front of the thing they’re labeling, which must be an executable statement even if it is merely the NULL statement. So is END; not considering as a statement then ?
I need to know why its throwing error. I also refer Oracle docs but it doesn't mention anything like this.

Documentation changes between versions; sometimes newer versions don't contain useful information which existed in previous versions.
In 10g GOTO statement, it says:

The GOTO statement branches unconditionally to a statement label or block label. The label must be unique within its scope and must precede an executable statement or a PL/SQL block. The GOTO statement transfers control to the labelled statement or block

END; is not an executable statement; NULL; (or your x := 100;) are.

OK, so BEGIN and END are not executable statements then what are they? i am not understanding this part

I don't know whether they fit into any kind of "statements"; these are keywords used to mark beginning and end of a PL/SQL block.


So is END; not considering as a statement then ?

No, it is a keyword.
From the documentation on blocks:

A PL/SQL block is defined by the keywords DECLARE, BEGIN, EXCEPTION, and END. These keywords divide the block into a declarative part, an executable part, and an exception-handling part. Only the executable part is required. A block can have a label.

and

Because a block is an executable statement, it can appear in another block wherever an executable statement is allowed.

So the entire block is a statement; the keywords that define it (including END) are not statements.
It wouldn't make sense to just execute END; in isolation - it only has meaning as a block keyword, not as a statement.
